# Работа с сетями/интернетом

Tags: delphi

Здравствуйте!
Всем известно, что компоненты с вкладок `Indy` могут легко реализовать
сетевую работу компьютеров локальной сети, отправку емейла и прочую роскошь.
Так вот, хотелось бы узнать, есть ли такие компоненты, позволяющие организовать
отсылку определенного текста на другой компьютер, но только ПО ИНТЕРНЕТУ.
Ведь в дельфи делаются интернет-чаты и прочие интернет-приложения.
Пробовал сокеты, но они тоже работают только в пределах локальной сети...

Answer (score 3):

- Пробуйте сокеты, до тех пор пока не заработает )
- Почитайте про построение клиент-серверных систем. Имейте в виду, сервер должен иметь "белый" IP-адрес, чтобы вы могли подключиться к нему с клиента.
- Поизучайте как работают p2p системы.

В любом случае, для передачи/приема данных вы будете пользоваться сокетами.

Comment: И как же я интересно смогу подключиться к белому аймишнику из интернета? Ведь этот самый айпи будет принадлежать локальной сети

Comment: Нет, не будет. На то он и белый. Условный пример. IP-адрес для `ya.ru` - `77.88.21.3`. Это адрес сервера в интернете ("белый"), что позволяет нам, набрав его в браузере, подключиться к серверу. 

Надеюсь понятно изложил. Могу порекомендовать [отличную книгу](http://www.ozon.ru/context/detail/id/1354276/), которая поможет вам во всем разобраться.

Answer (score 2):

Пример "рассылки определенного текста":

Клиент:
ставим на форму компонент TCPClient, настраиваем RemotePort и RemoteHost

отправляем текст:

```
procedure TForm1.Button1Click(Sender: TObject);
 begin
  if TcpClient1.Connect then
   begin
    TcpClient1.Sendln(Edit1.text);
    TcpClient1.Disconnect;
   end;
 end;
```

Сервер:
ставим на форму компонент TCPServer, настраиваем LocalPort и LocalHost

принимаем текст:

```
procedure TForm1.TcpServer1Accept(Sender: TObject;
ClientSocket: TCustomIpClient);
 begin
  s:= ClientSocket.Receiveln;
  memo1.lines.add(s);
 end;
```

Comment: Не работает это! TidTCPServer/TidTCPClient предназначены для внутренних сетей!

Comment: @Asen: 

1. Читайте внимательнее, в вышеуказанном примере используются `TTCPServer` и `TTCPClient` с вкладки Internet, а не с Indy Clients/Servers.

2. Проверьте код, перед тем как кричать, что он не работает.

3. Где вы прочитали, что "`TidTCPServer/TidTCPClient` предназначены для внутренних сетей". Для протоколов TCP/IP нет существенной разницы между Интернетом и локальными сетями.

Лучше расскажите присутствующим, в каких условиях вы испытывали клиент и, что важнее, сервер. Локальная машина с белым IPшником? VDS?  Dedicated server? Две машины за NAT-ами с динамическими IP-адресами?

Comment: Еще не помешало бы показать уже ваш код, чтобы не гадать на кофейной гуще.

Comment: Да, и правда, я использовал не те компоненты. Беру свои слова обратно. Испытал ваш код - в локалке все работает, как меняю свой ip c 127.0.0.1 на "белый" 95.165.2.188, то просто ничего не происходит... в чем может быть дело? как правильно настроить эти компоненты?

Comment: И все-таки, где вы запускаете сервер и где - клиент?